# Woocommerce multiple taxes with same rates adds as different values.

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to calculate tax according Indian GST tax norms. I have setup the basic tax settings. And tax rates as below.

- If state = GJ => 2.5% SGST & 2.5% IGST will be applied.
- If state != GJ => 5% CGST will be applied.

Taxes are being added. But when state is GJ two different value shows up as taxes. Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

> Ideally it should be

1. Subtotal = 5329.19
2. 2.5% SGST = 133.23
3. 2.5% IGST = 133.23
4. Total = 5595.65

> Here is the Basic Tax settings.

[image]

> Here is the Tax class table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before calculating SGST, CGST is being added to Subtotal, so that the difference in CGST & SGST value. Remove tick marks from *Compound* column to resolve this issue.